# How to correctly cast a pointer-to-struct to pointer-to-other-struct in modern C++ when calling legacy C API?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

When calling a legacy C API such as [`getnameinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getnameinfo.3.html), what's the right way in modern C++ to correctly cast a pointer-to-struct argument to a pointer-to-another-struct, which has similar layout, but which isn't related to the class hierarchy of the original struct?

For example, `getnameinfo` accepts for its first parameter a `const struct sockaddr *`, but it should also work when handing it a `const struct sockaddr_storage *`. However, AFAIK simply `reinterpret_cast`-ing the pointer is considered UB by the C++ standard.

In the above example, given a `sockaddr_storage` object, what's the right way to pass a pointer to it to `getnameinfo`?

Comment: It may be UB, but it is also irrelevant. Just do the cast, it's fine. The socket API needs a pointer, and that's it. Not yours to worry. Being a C structure, you can expect it's just the same address (there's no virtual members or inheritance or any such thing).

Comment: Casting a pointer, alone, is never UB. Only *accessing* the pointer - and the library-call boundary is opaque so it won't cause problems.

Comment: Also, the "common initial subsequence" rule applies here.

Comment: @o11c Reference to the rule you're referencing? All I could find was regarding a case where the two structs are declared in a union, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be misreading the standard, but since those types are standard layout types, it's not UB if you access their common initial sub-sequence. I believe [[class.mem/23]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#23) is why:

> In a standard-layout union with an active member of struct type T1, it is permitted to read a non-static data member m of another union member of struct type T2 provided m is part of the common initial sequence of T1 and T2; the behavior is as if the corresponding member of T1 were nominated.

This is an explicit permission for unions, that theoretically could simply be accomplished with compiler magic. But in effect I believe it means that for standard layout classes, the common initial sequence has the same layout in memory.

Now let's consider [[basic.lval/8.6]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#8.6):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through
>   a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is
>   undefined:
>
> - ...
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members (including,
>     recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or
>     contained union),
> - ...

When you dereference the reinterpreted pointer, you obtain a glvalue of an aggregate that includes the type of the member you access. Since that member belongs to the common initial sequence, all should be well.

I doubt there's a sane implementation where this will not work across a library boundary.